# Nested if-statements, clean code, and being Pythonic, with controller/keyboard input

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame

First the background: I use Python and PyGame. I've experimented with writing my own input/controller module, that allows users to remap controls in any way they like. This necessarily requires that my code be written to handle different types of input (for example, keyboard keys, controller buttons, and controller axes/hats/etc.)

For example, if the button "Right" is mapped to an arrow key, the code to handle `GetPush("Right")` or `GetRelease("Right")` would be somewhat different than if it were mapped to a control stick being pushed along a certain axis. To help take care of this, I made a helper function `__GetButtonType()` which -- as the name replies -- returns what type of button it is. For the code shown here, buttons are referred to as strings. The first letter of the string denotes the button type, and the rest denotes the button. For example `k97` refers to the keyboard key with a value of `97`. (the A key.)

Now for the issue at hand. My code does what I want it to do. But as I began cleaning it up, I came across one part that bothered me. I have the following segment of code which handles presses from the keyboard. (The `DoSomething()` functions replace entirely unrelated code, that I assume does not matter for the question at hand.)

```
for n in TheController.ControlMap:
    if __GetButtonType(n)=="key":
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == int(n[1:]): DoSomething()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == int(n[1:]): DoSomethingElse()
```

Something about this just looks a little off to me. It may be that the `if event.key == int(n[1:])` condition is repeated. That seems wasteful. However, if `event.key` is not `KEYUP` or `KEYDOWN`, then the event will not have a key attribute (that is how pyGame works, that isn't of my design.) This means that the condition `if (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == int(n[1:])` will throw an error whenever the `event.type` is something else.

However, I thought about it a bit, and realized that I CAN shorten the code by one line by structuring it in the following way:

```
for n in TheController.ControlMap:
    if event.type == KEYUP:
        if __GetButtonType(n)=="key" and event.key == int(n[1:]): DoSomething()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if __GetButtonType(n)=="key" and event.key == int(n[1:]): DoSomethingElse()
```

Both code snippets work. Both do the same thing. The first one looks a bit easier to read, but not by a whole lot. The second one uses fewer lines. My question is this:

Which style is "better"? Does one perform faster than the other one would by a non-negligible amount? Or is one just considered "poor practice?" Maybe they both are, in fact. I am still relatively new to programming.

Thank you,

- Chris

Comment: That would definitely make this part of the code look a lot cleaner. No doubt. But if I'm not misunderstanding something, wouldn't that just relocate the parsing issue elsewhere? The DoSomething function would still have to use nested if statements to figure out what to do with the arguments, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your statements have one same feature which would make people cringe. Equivalent `if` statements are repeated twice. This is no good because it clatters your code and is absolutely unnecessary:

```
if event.type in [KEYUP, KEYDOWN] and __GetButtonType(n)=="key" and event.key == int(n[1:]):
    if event.type == KEYUP:
        DoSomething()
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
        DoSomethingElse()
```

Here the first condition makes sure that you don't get an error on `event.key`.

Also use `elif` because the options are mutually exclusive. Simple `else` will also suffice, but I'd leave `elif` for the purpose of readability. Also you can hide this into `DoSomething(event.type)`.

---

Another option which could look ugly or pretty depending on who you ask is collapse it all into a flat if-else:

```
if event.type in [KEYUP, KEYDOWN] and __GetButtonType(n)=="key" and event.key == int(n[1:]):
    (DoSomething if event.type == KEYUP else DoSomethingElse)()
```

But that's getting a bit weird... Still, it works.

---

Performance-wise, there is absolutely nothing to worry about here. Optimization is a whole other topic and the first thing to optimize would be program design / algorithm rather than local low-importance commands.

Comment: Very informative answer. Much appreciated. This doesn't just answer the question, it explains it in a way that my future code will hopefully be better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

on the lines of what 'sashkello' mentioned, I generally have the below block of code common in my pygame programs.

```
   for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT :
               do_something()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
               do_something_else()
```